# Raspbmc + HDMI + AV receiver = screen changes resolutions

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, config.txt

This is my setup:

- Raspberry Pi w/Raspbmc
- 8GB Transcend SDHC card
- Yamaha RX-V1900 receiver
- Westinghouse 40" flat panel TV

When the Pi is **directly connected to the TV** by HDMI, the output is sharp (TV switches to the HDMI output of the Pi) and the screen doesn't change resolutions every 5 seconds.

When the Pi is **connected to the TV through the AV receiver when it's powered up**, it appears that the Pi cannot detect the TV's resolution; it keeps rotating through resolutions trying to find one that works.

If I power up the Pi **attached directly to the TV** (so that the screen is properly detected) **and then plug it into the receiver**, the screen stays perfect (no resolution changes).

I have tried a number of `config.txt` options but nothing seems to work.

Using the `tvservice` application I was able to find the resolution that appears to be the best:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
state: HPD high|HDMI mode|HDCP off|composite off (0x12001a), 1366x768 @ 60Hz, progressive

pi@raspbmc:/var/log$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 7 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
  (native) mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz, interlaced
           mode 6: 720x480 @ 60Hz, interlaced
           mode 7: 720x480 @ 60Hz, interlaced

pi@raspbmc:/var/log$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 10 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 6: 640x480 @ 75Hz, progressive
           mode 9: 800x600 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 11: 800x600 @ 75Hz, progressive
           mode 16: 1024x768 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 17: 1024x768 @ 70Hz, progressive
           mode 18: 1024x768 @ 75Hz, progressive
           mode 28: 1280x800 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 81: 1366x768 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 85: 1280x720 @ 60Hz, progressive

pi@raspbmc:~$ /opt/vc/bin/edidparser edid.dat
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing edid.dat...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 98x58 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is Westinghouse
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is SK-42H240S
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 49-76 Hz, horizontal is 15-49 kHz, max pixel clock is 90 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:40 hs:32 hbp:58 vfp:3 vs:5 vbp:40 pixel clock:73 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 60 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found preferred DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
```

This is my latest `/boot/config.txt` file:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ cat /boot/config.txt
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_edid_file=1
arm_freq=800 
force_turbo=1
disable_overscan=1
gpu_mem_256=128
gpu_mem_512=256
```

What is going on here? Is there any way that I can get the Pi to detect the resolution of the TV **through** the receiver?

Comment: hdmi_mode and hdmi_group solved my problem of routing my HDMI through a receiver too. Thank you to this page!

Comment: Did you get a solution? I'm facing the same exact issue, even the hdmi_safe is not working. Regards,
Sergio S.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following 2 lines to your config.txt:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=4
```

This sets the used resolution to CEA (`hdmi_group=1`) and 1280x720p (`hdmi_mode=4`).
Add this to your config.txt and reboot.

No idea if this will work but it selects a resolution permanently (you can of course change it by editing your config.txt again).

Answer (score 1):

Awesome suggestions. Attached raspberry pi -> receiver (HDMI) -> TV (HDMI) and running Openelec. Every time I would switch sources on my receiver, every time I tried to go back to raspberry pi I received basically a blank screen (input not detected/supported). I added these lines to my config.sys (Added to the very bottom, after all the hash tags ###):

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_mode=16

(Mode 16 = 1080p @ 60Hz)
Now I can switch inputs on my receiver and go back to the raspberry pi without problems. Thanks!

Update - this did not end up working consistently. I'm thinking it may have to do with CEC control/command.